# Why is variable capturing in lambdas so complex?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering about the new C++11 lambda functionality, a wonderful addition in my humble opinion, but I really don't get the whole variable capturing part. In short my question comes down to "why did the committee decide for this and did not just use `[&]` functionality (possibly with a keyword then)?"

At first I thought 'wow, `C++` does it again and gives us even more powerful lambdas, sad of the syntax though'. However, then I tried to think of real, useful cases for this complex lambdas I couldn't think of any.

First, you obviously need it if you want to mix pass-by-reference and pass-by-value. So then the question is, do we actually need pass-by-value in the lambda construct. What is wrong with creating a temporary inside the lambda body. This is similar if you want a copy of an upper scope variable in the body of a loop, we also don't write `[x] while(...) { ... }`. Am I missing something here that makes passing by value really necessary and you cannot fall back on constructing a copy yourself?

So we come to the second part, suppose pass-by-value is not necessary, with the current syntax you can specify which variables you want to capture and which not. Once again I do not see the benefit. The lambda is written in local scope, same as the variable. Why would you need to restrict access to these variables? It's not an interface, not another context and it shouldn't even be another programmer. It won't optimize it for compilers either, because using `[&]` or mentioning each used variable yourself should come down to the same code.

Now, I do know I don't grasp C++ to its' fullest and the people on the committee know better than me. So, which of my arguments are wrong (or what did I miss) and why did they not just decide on using the `[&]` functionality, preferably with a keyword instead of the current (quite ugly) syntax.

Comment: The lambda itself is a complete object that you can pass around, e.g. store it somewhere or return it from a function. So capturing by value may be your only option! Allowing explicit capture lists is useful, too: A captureless lambda is convertible to a function pointer, but capturing ones aren't, so it's good to be able to be explicit.

Comment: This question is like asking "why are there different types of sheep?"

Comment: @Tomalak: If sheep were engineered, would that be such a weird question? Also, I do not understand the "not constructive" close votes. I asked a real question about a real construct and I do want the technical answers (which I got). See the answer below (and Kerrek SB's comment), which are not at all personal opinions but valid technical reasons I missed why this is necessary ... .

Comment: @Killian: It's more suited to a chat room or message board.

Comment: @KillianDS: pretty much any question about standards rationale is liable to attract close votes recently. Recently someone even argued in comments that such questions are inherently subjective, since the committee's reasons for doing things are some combination of inscrutable and subjective. Plenty disagree, but SO is carefully designed so that if 5 people out of thousands think your question should be closed, then it is. It's a fashion thing, really, but it's how SO is supposed to work, it's supposed to be easy to close things. It's fairly easy to reopen too, of course.

Comment: Is the question really about 'What went on during the Standardization process?'/'How did we end up with so-and-so syntax?', or rather what capture lists are about and how to use them? If the latter, you can probably reword it to not reference the Standardization process and not get closed. (Not that I hold against with those questions, but ah well.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need by-reference for efficiency.

You need by-value to allow the function object to leave the scope of the local variable which it captures.

```
std::function<void()> get_foo (const std::string & bar)
{
    return [=] () {something with bar;}
}
```

Comment: Leaving a scope with a captured variable in an instance of the [Funarg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem).

Comment: It's only a problem for references. C++ likes its types to be value-like and is designed with this in mind. The funarg problem is easy if we copy everything (assuming the copy operators are properly defined), references are the exception that makes it hard. Funnily enough, we are usually taught to prefer references where possible. Read http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 2):

...and the decision **against a new keyword** is mainly because of backward compatibility. If you introduce new keywords you might break existing code which uses that keyword as a regular identifier.

Even if you break only 0.01% of existing code, you do not want to create costs for such a change, if you can prevent it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380599/is-c14-adding-new-keywords-to-c I don't agree with their philosophy though. If code breaks, you hire people to fix it. The standard shouldn't be handicapped due to 30+ years old code breaking. Why do we have software engineers?